# backBarButtonItem BackButtonBackgroundVerticalPositionAdjustment

Tags: xcode, ios5, ios6, uibarbuttonitem, uiappearance

I'm trying to set the vertical position of a back UIBarButtonItem and it's having no affect. I don't want to do this as a UIAppearance selector as I just want this to be used in one class. What am I doing wrong?

I have tried this in the parent and child view controllers.

```
[self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem setBackButtonBackgroundVerticalPositionAdjustment:-10 forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Thanks!

Comment: Where do you use it? Try to put it in the ViewDidLoad action.